# Change default selected country based on GeoIP

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

I have changed the default country of store by below setting.

`Admin -> System Configuration -> General -> Countries options -> Default country`

But, now I want to change the country selected based on Customer GeoIP.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to get the customer IP address information by doing code as below:

Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress

Add this above code to construct function in your file and after that get the Ip address for the customer by using "$this->remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();", this way you will get an IP address. Now second based on IP address you need to grep the information of address where the customer belongs to. You can use this code to fetch customer address information.

$ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=x.x.x.x"));

You will get the country code and other information as well.

Comment: You don't really expect that on each page view the geo json data should be fetched and parsed by the server? The site you mention uses the Maxmind database, a much better solution would be to implement the maxmind geo lookup locally in a custom module and perform cached ip lookups on a local geo ip database.